# Banking overseas when your US job pays you via Direct Deposit

Tags: banking

For those who travel to different European countries and do not spend significant time (more than one year) at any one location, how do you handle your direct deposits and transfers from your US job?

Comment: Keep a US bank account, have the money deposited there, then withdraw/transfer it out from there?

Answer (score 4):

I am in a similar situation and here is what I do.

I have my US back account to continue the deposits.  I then opened an account here in Europe and use xe.com to transfer the money.  The advantage of using xe or other online transfer service is known exchange rates and being able to manage the transfers online.

Your other option is the wire the money from your US account to your european bank, but depending on which banks you use, there will be fees and the exchange rate may not be very good.

The other option I also use is having a PayPal debit card linked to my US checking account.  You can use it for cash withdrawals in Europe and they do not charge a separate exchange rate or ATM fees and the exchange rate is very competitive.  However, they currently do not have a card with a chip in it, so you will have to find an ATM that takes regular cards and it tends to not work in restaurants, groceries, etc.